# Error to build AWS Lambda Node 14arm64 with Sharp on a Docker image

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker

I'm changing a node setup from `node 14 x64` to `node 14 arm64` in an Amazon ECR (Docker) entry.

It build with no problem when I use this image: `FROM aws/lambda/nodejs:14` and this command to install sharp `RUN npm install --platform=linux sharp`

Now I need to use `Node 14 arm64` image, but it launches this error while building with Sharp JS (Linux arm 64):

**Dockerfile:**

```sh
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/nodejs:14-arm64

# Exec commands
COPY index.js package.json ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}
COPY fonts ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/fonts/
COPY src ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/src/

# Commands
RUN npm cache clean --force
RUN rm -rf node_modules
RUN npm install --arch=arm64 --platform=linux sharp

CMD ["index.handler"]
```

**Build command:**

```sh
docker build -t my-project-v1 .
docker tag my-project-v1:latest {ACCOUNT}.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/my-project-v1:latest
docker push {ACCOUNT}.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/my-project-v1:latest
```

**Error:**

```sh
=> ERROR [6/8] RUN npm install                                                                                                                  7.3s
------                                                                                                                                                
 > [6/8] RUN npm install:                                                                                                                             
#10 2.231 npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.       
#10 2.249 npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.3.2: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.                                                                       
#10 6.947                                                                                                                                             
#10 6.947 > sharp@0.29.3 install /var/task/node_modules/sharp
#10 6.947 > (node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install) || (node install/can-compile && node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)
#10 6.947 
#10 7.046 sharp: Installation error: Use with glibc 2.26 requires manual installation of libvips >= 8.11.3
#10 7.046 sharp: Please see https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/install for required dependencies
#10 7.172 npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@~2.3.2 (node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
#10 7.173 npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"arm64"})
#10 7.174 
#10 7.234 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
#10 7.235 npm ERR! errno 1
#10 7.242 npm ERR! sharp@0.29.3 install: `(node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install) || (node install/can-compile && node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)`
#10 7.242 npm ERR! Exit status 1
#10 7.243 npm ERR! 
#10 7.244 npm ERR! Failed at the sharp@0.29.3 install script.
#10 7.244 npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
#10 7.261 
#10 7.262 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
#10 7.262 npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-01-10T13_28_10_709Z-debug.lo
```

Answer (score 2):

The error message said that the problem is related with `libvips`: `sharp: Installation error: Use with glibc 2.26 requires manual installation of libvips >= 8.11.3`. Searching in the [official sharp documentation](https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/install#aws-lambda) I found that on machines other than Linux x64 (like in your case: Linux arm64), you should ignore global `libvips` updating the `SHARP_IGNORE_GLOBAL_LIBVIPS` environment variable:

```sh
npm install
SHARP_IGNORE_GLOBAL_LIBVIPS=1 npm install --arch=x64 --platform=linux sharp
```

so, you should update your `Dockerfile` to the following:

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/nodejs:14-arm64

# Exec commands
COPY index.js package.json ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}
COPY fonts ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/fonts/
COPY src ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/src/

# Commands
RUN npm cache clean --force
RUN rm -rf node_modules

## update the dockerfile with the following lines:
RUN npm install
RUN SHARP_IGNORE_GLOBAL_LIBVIPS=1 npm install --arch=x64 --platform=linux sharp

CMD ["index.handler"]
```

Comment: I tried this, but the error is the same. I think that `public.ecr.aws/lambda/nodejs:14-arm64` image haven't support to sharp library yet because `amazon/aws-lambda-nodejs:14` image is perfect with sharp x64.

Comment: using the same `dockerfile` that you shown above, I was able to reproduce the error and also to fix it with `SHARP_IGNORE_GLOBAL_LIBVIPS=1`. Are you sure that the error showed in `stdout` is the same?